# Symfony2 join not used, unnesessary queries fired

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, twig

I have following problem:
my Query with joins contains all the nesessary data but symfony / twig creates more queries
each {{ entity.group.name }} produces a new query

controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/gameplan", name="game_plan")
 * @Template()
 * //@Secure(roles="ROLE_USER")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('OnemediaFeedFighterBundle:Game')->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->leftJoin('q.group', 'g')
            ->leftJoin('q.teamGame', 'tg')
            ->leftJoin('tg.Team', 't')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

    return array('entities' => $entities);
}
```

template:

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Game plan</h1>

    {% for entity in entities %}
       {{ entity.place }}<br />{{ entity.group.name }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the `->select("q, g")`